# Kendo UI 2019 return undefined in use requirejs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, requirejs

I'm using requirejs and kendo ui 2019 in my project, all of libraries that I used are true and response true but in case of kendo ui I can not use that because that returns me undefined, what can I do? Please tell me the solution :(

My config file:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js',
  paths: {
    bootstrapBundle: 'libraries/bootstrap.bundle.min',
    bootstrap: 'libraries/bootstrap.min',
    jquery: 'libraries/jquery-3.4.1.min',
    customScroll: 'libraries/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min',
    kendoUI: 'libraries/kendo.all.min',
    popper: 'libraries/popper',
    controlesList: 'custom/ControlesList',
    dropInCol: 'custom/DropInColumn',
    dropInDropzones: 'customScripts/DropInDropzones'
  },
  shim: {
    "kendoUI": {
      deps: ["jquery"]
    }
  }
});
```

In use Kendo UI:

```
require(['kendoUI', function(kendo) {
  console.log('kendo : ', kendo);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the source code of Kendo UI and seems that is support RequireJS out of the box - https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/js/kendo.all.min.js

Please try to remove the `shim` from your config and try again :)

Comment: Thanks for your help , i try your solution but that did not work yet , my project is in danger i should to use requirejs and  Kendo UI both but now i can not do that